# fgetc is not stopping my loop

Tags: c, loops, fgetc

```
int ch;
char Name1[24], Name2[24],*p1,*p2;  
while ((ch = fgetc(inz)) != EOF){

            fseek(inz, -1, SEEK_CUR);

        fgets(Name1, 24, inz);
        fgets(Name2, 24, inz);
        p1 = Name1;
        p2 = Name2;
        p1 += 3;
        p2 += 3;

        if (atoi(p1) > atoi(p2)){
            fseek(inz, -46, SEEK_CUR);              
            fputs(Name2, inz);              
            fputs(Name1, inz);              

        }
        fseek(inz, -23, SEEK_CUR);      
        i --;
    }
```

I have this code. inz is my file in r+ mod. and i want to compare each string to next one and sort them depend on the 4th character. the function is working but..its unstoppable it runs forever...
**I have tried to change the int ch; to char too. Still didn't work, and feof didn't work.

Comment: Where is "i" defined and what it does? I think that you never reach the EOF as you are repeatedly calling fseek  to rewind the file. I suggest to start writing the ordered list in another file.

Comment: On each iteration of the loop, print out all variables after you've read them in (`ch`, `Name1`, `Name2`, `p1`, and `p2`).  Also, print the result of `ftell()` so you can see where you are in the file.  That should give you a good idea of where you went wrong in your logic.

Comment: Please present the file after the change to be expected with a sample of the file.

Comment: Each time your read a char in the file, you go backward (at least one position) in the file. This is a never ending loop as you will never be able to reach the end of file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1) You're making the assumption that each line is at least 4 characters long (plus newline). If the line were smaller than 4 bytes you would not be sorting based on the string itself and may be sorting based on uninitialized memory.

2) You said you want to compare each line based on the 4th character, but you're actually comparing it based on the string starting from the 4th character. You're converting it to integer, which means you're also assuming that the line contains an numeric value.

3) You're assuming each string took up 24 bytes in the file. I guess you're assuming each string is 23 characters long plus a newline? Is this assumption valid? If lines can be shorter than 24 bytes then this code is incorrect:

```
fseek(inz, -46, SEEK_CUR);
```

Instead you want to rewind back to the actual total length of both strings plus two newlines. Even if the strings are 23 bytes, you're not factoring in the newlines here, so you want to be rewinding -48 not -46.

4) When writing the string back to the file you are using fputs which does not include the newline character.

5) You're not really sorting the file, you're just going through one iteration of a bubble sort. You're reordering the current two lines based on a comparison, but that doesn't sort the entire file. So the logic of the sort is also wrong.

It would be cleaner to read each line, stick it in an array, sort the array based on the criteria you mentioned, then write it back to the file.

So aside from all that, why does the loop never end?

The last line in your loop is this:

```
fseek(inz, -23, SEEK_CUR);
```

This means it *always* goes back 23 bytes just before trying to get the next character (fgetc).  You'll never see the EOF then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will only get an EOF if you do a `fgets` with the file pointer already positioned at end of file. And the instruction just before the only `fgetc` for which you test the return value is `fseek(inz, -23, SEEK_CUR);`.

That means that when you have reached end of file, you first go 23 bytes back, successfully read something, and probably get an EOF on any of the two following `fgets` for which the returned value is ignored. And repeat that forever...

What should you do? At least test the return value for each and every read function:

```
    if (fgets(Name1, 24, inz) == NULL) break;
    if (fgets(Name2, 24, inz) == NULL) break;
```

But it is not all. Unless you are **really sure** that all your lines will always have exactly 23 characters and the file is open in binary mode (or you are on Linux) never use such `fseek`. The only reasonable way is to store a position with `ftell` and then `fseek` to that position.

And last but not least, your algorythm goes one line back to read in Name1 what you have just read in Name2. You should instead swap p1 and p2, always read into p2 and compare p1 and p2

This one will sort a file whatever are the line sizes provided they are all shorter than SIZE but longer than 4:

```
size_t oldpos = 0, tmp;
char Name1[SIZE], Name2[SIZE],*p1,*p2;
p1 = Name1;
p2 = Name2;
/* read first line and note position after it */
if (fgets(p1, SIZE, inz) == NULL) return;
tmp = ftell(inz);
/* loop reading in p2 */
while (fgets(p2, SIZE, inz) != NULL){

    if (atoi(p1 + 3) > atoi(p2 + 3)){
        /* swap last two lines */
        fseek(inz, oldpos, SEEK_SET);              
        fputs(p2, inz);
        fputs(p1, inz);          
        /* and go back to beginning of file - not optimal but robust */    
        fseek(inz, 0, SEEK_SET);
        /* again last line in p1 and note position */
        fgets(p1, SIZE, inz);
        oldpos = 0;
        tmp = ftell(inz);
    }
    else {
        /* order is ok untill here, note new position and swap buffers */
        oldpos = tmp;
        tmp = ftell(inz);
        swap(&p1, &p2);
    }
}
```